# Urls with multiple parameters not being created properly

Tags: php, yii2, url-routing, yii2-advanced-app

I can't seem to get pretty urls to be generated properly. My frontend config is as follows:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'item/<id:\d+>/<slug>' => 'item/view',
        'category/<id:\d+>/<slug>' => 'category/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ]
],
```

The following url array:

```
['item/view', 'id' => 4, 'slug' => 'shark-chomp-socks']
```

generates the url `http://example.com/item/4?slug=shark-chomp-socks` instead of `http://example.com/item/4/shark-chomp-socks`.

If I manually type in the expected url (`http://example.com/item/4/shark-chomp-socks`), the url resolves correctly without any errors.

How can I get it to generate the url properly?

Comment: maybe this would be helpful, albeit you've two more rules:  http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x21cdtl_4-removing-question-mark-from-url-in-yii-framework_tech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules in my common config were causing the issue. I removed the `urlManager` entry in `common/config/main.php` and the urls were created properly. I had this in `common/config/main.php`:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => [
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ]
],
```

Since, the `frontend/config/main.php` is merged into `common/config/main.php` in my `frontend/web/index.php`, the rules in `frontend` were appended to those in `common` and duplicates removed resulting in the following order:

```
'rules' => [
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    'item/<id:\d+>/<slug>' => 'item/view',
    'category/<id:\d+>/<slug>' => 'category/view',
]
```

---

**TL;DR**: Remove any rules from any config file that is loaded before the one in which your custom rules are.